# how to I make a Navigation Property be mandatory in the EF designer? (e.g. make Node always have a NodeType)

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

how to I make a Navigation Property be mandatory in the EF designer? (e.g. make Node always have a NodeType)

i.e. so that in the database the NODE foreign key to NODE_TYPE has to be set/have a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify this on the Association, multiplicity = 1 to ...

Comment: oh, I'd tried that, but perhaps I didn't test properly - I'll check